# How to pass parameters from jsp to jsx file?

Tags: java, reactjs, jsp, jsx

Java 1.8, if no parameters, my test jsp calling jsx works fine. The question is how to pass parameters from jsp to jsx, so far i cannot see the message.

In the jsp file, i'm using react 15.4 for testing, but will use the more recent versions.

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-standalone/6.22.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="alert.jsx">
    <Alert1 toWhat="sth...." />;
</script>
```

The alert.jsx

```
const Alert1 = (props) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <h5>{props.toWhat} </h5>,
        document.getElementById('example')
    )
};
```

I won't use the React.createClass(). We want to stay close to recent React.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As quick & dirty solution - try with global variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.myProperty= '${myJspProperty}';
</script>
```

then from React component:

```
const Alert1 = (props) => {
    props.toWhat = window.myProperty;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <h5>{props.toWhat} </h5>,
        document.getElementById('example')
    )
};
```

Comment: That seems to be working, 1 more question, how to make window.myProperty as a json object ? i tried {v1: '${myJspProperty}', v2: "sth"}  But not working.

Comment: By using ordinary JSON.parse() function: window.myProperty= JSON.parse('${myJspProperty}');